# BOOST Library inverse output -1.#IND

Tags: c++, boost, matrix-inverse

I'm using BOOST library for inversing a matrix and it is giving me bad results like -1.#IND

I was wondering if anybody ran into this problem.

the code is like this:

```
void tryLib(){
    AG_Matrix AG_Matrix_1=AG_Matrix(4,4,3.0);
    AG_Matrix AG_Matrix_4=AG_Matrix_1.Inverse();
    std::cout<<AG_Matrix_4(1,1)<<'\n';
}
```

`AG_Matrix` is a type definition and the console output is this:

```
-1.#IND
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I modified the code and the results are good now, yet I'm not quite sure what the reason was. I will mention the reason here, when I discover it...The determinant was zero, that was the problem as answered below by Mr.Llama ...

Comment: You should at least post a minimal program giving the same error along with your question... Without that, nobody can answer.

Comment: Please include the code you're using to get the error.  Without any code to look at, there's not much StackOverflow can do to help.  Please see how to make a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 4x4 matrix with all values equal to 3.0 is a [singular matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularMatrix.html) and has no inverse, hence the invalid floating point that's returned.
I would recommend checking the matrix's determinant before you run an invert on it.

Your problem isn't a code issue, it's a math issue.

Comment: Thanks, that was right. I should implement a conditional statement in the code so that the inverse would be calculated only if the determinant is nonzero.